# Exact sequences in category theory

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I am trying to understand exact sequences.

Suppose that we have an exact sequence $$0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{g}C\rightarrow0$$ and a morphism $B\xrightarrow{x}D$ such that $x\circ f=0$.

I do not understand why that implies that $x=y\circ g$ for some morphism $y$.

Since $x\circ f=0$, then $x= h\circ \text{coker}f$ for some morphism $h$.
By the same reason, $g=t\circ \text{coker}f$.

I also know that $\text{ker}(\text{coker}f)=\text{ker}g$ because the complex is exact.

However, I do not know how to conclude from here that $x=y\circ g$.

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Show that $g$ is a cokernel of $f$, that is show that the arrow $t$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Since the axiomatization of abelian categories is self dual, it might be more intuitive to work in the opposite category and first prove that $f'(x')=0$ implies the existence of a $y'$ such that $x'=g'(y')$.

Comment: what definition of short exact sequence are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in abelian categories all epimorphisms and monomorphisms are normal, $g$ and $f$ are normal. Hence, $$g \cong \text{coker}(\text{ker}g).$$ Moreover, by exactness, $\text{coker}f=\text{coim}g$. That is, $$\text{coker}f\cong \text{coker}(\text{ker}g).$$ Hence, $g\cong \text{coker}f.$